# Circuit to drive 8 IGBT gate drivers using 2 PWM pins on Arduino

Tags: arduino, circuit-design, pwm, gate-driving, adafruit

I am using digital pins 9 and 10 to generate a 10kHz PWM on Arduino Uno. So, I got 2 PWMs.
But I need to drive 8 IGBT gate drivers using these 2 PWMs (4 IGBTs using PWM1 and other 4 IGBTs using PWM2).

When I connected 2 PWM pin of Arduino to 4+4 gate drivers, the Arduino went bad and doesn't work any more because the gate drivers might have pulled in a lot of current. So, I was wondering if there is any product or extension that I can use to avoid this problem and power 8 gate drivers using 2 PWM signals.

I see an Adafruit extension board https://www.adafruit.com/product/815#Slide3 but it has a frequency limitation of 1.5kHz.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Gate driver with 8 IGBTs schematic]

Comment: It is  possible to resolve without details of design, load and layout, but that requires a lot of questions that wastes time.

Comment: You should use IGBT Gate drivers. But which ones, and how to configure them? That depends on details of your design that you haven't provided, and a generic explanation is too involved to suit this site. Here's something to get you started https://www.power.com/zh-hant/downloads/documents/AN-1001_IGBT_and_MOSFET_Drivers_Correctly_Calculated.pdf

Comment: Show us a schematic of what you did.

Comment: Hello, @TonyStewartEE75, agree, I just added a picture of the schematic.

Comment: Hello @BruceAbbott, thanks you for the link, I have added the schematic now. I use 8 IGBT gate drivers and am using 2 PWM to switch 4+4 IGBTs at the same time as a half bridge.

Comment: Hello @brhans, I have just added a schematic.

Comment: What's the value on your decoupling capacitors? What does your layout look like?

Comment: Please make the schematic image large enough to read the designations, and provide values for the capacitors.

Comment: It's only me thinking that the immensely powerful GPIO of the AVR should be able to drive the gate drivers? I think it went faulty for something else (i.e. ground bounce or transients)